# I want the date to be in french format

Tags: php, wordpress

So the function below return the date in english format. I want it in frensh format, any ideas guys?

```
<?php if(get_field('jour_de_l’evenement')): 
        setlocale (LC_ALL, "fr_FR"); ?>
        <span class="first">
         <?php echo date('d',strtotime(get_field('jour_de_l’evenement'))); ?>
        <small>
        <?php print date('M',strftime(strtotime(get_field('jour_de_l’evenement')))); ?>
        </small></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can format dates any way you like using the DateTime class. 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-09-18 22:00:00');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i'); // or however else you want it.
```

You can pass in a specific date or not, if you don't it defaults to now.

Check the different formats here:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

You can also pass in a DateTimeZone as a second argument:

```
$timeZone = DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels');
$date = new DateTime('2014-09-18 22:00:00', $timeZone);
```